# Is there a way to make a function do something different the second time a number appears?

Tags: c++, random

Im trying to make a small program about the method in which the amount of money awarded to players at the end of a game is decided. So far I have used a RNG to simulate what happens in a round of the game but have gotten stuck. I want to find out how to design my code in order for it to do something different the second time the same number is generated from the RNG.

```
while (active==1)
{
    random=rand()%11+1;
    if (random==11)
    {
        bomb=1;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any responses :)

Comment: store a list of previous numbers and check the entire list each time.

Comment: Keep a collection of the generated numbers and check if the new number exists in the collection.

Comment: Why is this marked [tag:c++]? This is C, if you wish for this to be c++ please use the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header instead of using `rand`

Comment: @Mgetz C++03 is still C++

Comment: @Mgetz I think it should be tagged "C" and "C++", if only to provoke LightnessRacesInOrbit ;-).

Comment: @Angew so is C++98, that doesn't mean I shouldn't recommend the `<random>` header.

Comment: @Mgetz You can of course recommend it, but "Why is this marked C++? This is C" sounds like a bit more than a recommendation to me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a map of (number, count) pairs:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::size_t> number_frequencies;
while (active) {
    int number = random_number();
    ++number_frequencies[number];
    if (number_frequencies[number] == 2) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, for clarity, apply the following:

1. Define `MAX` to whatever maximum value you want to have (e.g., 11)
2. Use `random` between `0` and `MAX-1` (instead of between `1` and `MAX`)

Then, you can try to adjust the following piece of code to your requirements:

```
#define MAX 11
...
int count[MAX] = {0};
while (active == 1)
{
    random = rand()%MAX;
    count[random]++;
    ...
}
```

The `count` array indicates the number of times that each `random` value was generated.

So at each iteration, you can use `count[random]` in order to choose what action to take.

Comment: -1 for using preprocessor and rand(). You are a terrible C++ programmer. Don't do that stuff again.

Comment: @Puppy: You are terrible in knowing how to read between the lines and understand the problem at hand. OP's issue is **not language specific**. Obviously, he (or she) is using `rand` himself, and it just so happen that he is working with C++, as he might as well have worked with C. This is pretty clear and obvious from the context of the question. Yet, you (not surprisingly, as I have witnessed this here before), choose to "cling onto" language semantics, where OP has a lot more basic issues at hand (this is also obvious from the question at hand). Wow!!! Great applause for your great wisdom!!!

Comment: Right, that doesn't change the thing where your answer is with bad quality.